# PayPal integration in magento

Tags: php, paypal, magento-1.9

```
My magento version is 1.9.1
```

I tried to active PayPal in my site but the payment option not enabled in frontend store.

Is there any issue in magento or Please suggest steps to integrate PayPal.

Comment: please accept my ans

Answer (score 1):

Magento Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Sales - Payment Methods > Paypal (checkbox enable)! Voila

To get the full idea about Magento and Paypal integration, you must go through the Magento Article: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-for-your-magento-store. It's really very useful and great Article.

Cheers!!!

Comment: merchant country is india